# Playing videos saved in Camera Roll

Tags: iphone, ios

My iphone app can save photos and videos to the Camera Roll, and I was able to access the items in the camera roll too.

Displaying the photos from camera roll was easy, I did that using ALAssetsLibrary, and it shows perfectly in UIImage. I can access the videos too, and tried to display the video using MPMoviePlayerController.

Here's my code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
    [assetLibrary   enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos 
                    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
                        // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just videos.
                        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];

                          // Chooses the video at the last index
                          [group  enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:([group numberOfAssets]-1)] 
                                                   options:0
                                                usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop){   
                                                    if (alAsset){
                                                        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
                                                        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [representation url]];
                                                        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 300)];
                                                        [self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
                                                        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
                                                        [moviePlayer play];
                                                    }
                                                }
                           ];
                      }
                    failureBlock: ^(NSError *error){
                        // handle error
                        NSLog(@"No groups");
                    }
     ];
```

I only see a black frame, no video.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MPMoviePlayerViewController:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[representation url]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
[player.moviePlayer play];
[player release];
```

Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I write this for CollectionViewCell, you can update moviePlayerController.view.frame as you want.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]];
        moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);//self.view.frame;
        moviePlayerController.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        [moviePlayerController play];
```